# Weird React whack-a-mole bugs involving timeouts

Tags: reactjs, timeout

Weird situation here.  I have a whack-a-mole game in react.  There are 9 images in view.  When the game starts, one of these images randomly turns into a mole, which you can click (hit) to add to your score.  You can click "start" which will cause the game to continue until you hit "stop".  Or you can click "one minute" or "two minutes", which will cause the game to continue until 60 or 120 seconds have passed, OR until you click stop.

What I found, though, is if you chose the "one minute" option, and wait for that time to expire, the game will say you played for zero seconds and scored zero points, regardless of what you scored.  Why would this be?

I'm sorry but I basically posted the whole program because I really don't know where things are going wrong.

```
export default function App() {
  //I had to title 'hit' as 'hot' to avoid a bug where it said
  //it wasn't being read.  Weird

  const [playHitSound] = useSound(hot);
  const [playMissSound] = useSound(miss);

  const [holeStates, setHoleStates] = useState([
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty }
  ]);

  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [startBtnsDis, setStartBtnsDis] = useState(false);
  const [stopBtnDis, setStopBtnDis] = useState(true);

  const interval = useRef(null);
  const timeout = useRef(null);

  function start(time) {
    setStartBtnsDis(true);
    setStopBtnDis(false);
    //this if statement is for when I reimplement the "minute"
    //buttons

    interval.current = setInterval(moveMole, 1000);

    if (time == "one") {
      timeout.current = setTimeout(stop, 60 * 1000);
    }

    if (time == "two") {
      timeout.current = setTimeout(stop, 60 * 2000);
    }
  }

  function stop() {
    setStartBtnsDis(false);
    setStopBtnDis(true);
    clearInterval(interval.current);
    clearTimeout(timeout.current);

    let ratio = (score / seconds).toFixed(2);
    alert(
      "You scored " +
        score +
        " in " +
        seconds +
        " seconds, or " +
        ratio +
        " points per second."
    );
    setSeconds(0);
    setScore(0);

    //this sets all the holes back to empty, simple
    //aesthetic preference
    //BUG ALERT!  What's super weird is this doesn't happen
    //if you use the one minute button and wait for time to expire
    //why on Earth would that be?
    for (x of holeStates) {
      x.hole = empty;
    }
  }

  function moveMole() {
    //this adds to "seconds".  Since this function fires once a second,
    //it works nicely
    setSeconds((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);

    //this should reset all holes back to empty, ensuring
    //two moles won't appear at once.
    for (x of holeStates) {
      x.hole = empty;
    }

    //this should give us a random number representing holes 1 - 9
    let randomHoleNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    

    setHoleStates((pre) => {
      return pre.map((v, i) => {
        if (i === randomHoleNum) {
          return { ...v, hole: mole };
        }
        return { ...v, hole: empty };
      });
    });
  }

  //this function checks if you hit a mole, and adds to your score
  //if so
  function hit(number) {
    console.log(number);

    if (holeStates[number].hole == mole) {
      setScore(score + 1);

      //play hit sound doesn't work.  Why?
      playHitSound();
      setHoleStates((pre) => {
        return pre.map((v, i) => {
          if (i === number) {
            return { ...v, hole: whacked };
          }
          return { ...v, hole: empty };
        });
      });
    } else {
      playMissSound();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => start("inf")} id="start" disabled={startBtnsDis}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => start("one")} disabled={startBtnsDis}>
        One Minute
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => start("two")} disabled={startBtnsDis}>
        Two Minute
      </button>
      <button onClick={stop} id="stop" disabled={stopBtnDis}>
        Stop
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      Time: {seconds}
      <br />
      Score: {score}
      <br />
      <br />
      <img src={holeStates[0].hole} onClick={() => hit(0)} />
      <img src={holeStates[1].hole} onClick={() => hit(1)} />
      <img src={holeStates[2].hole} onClick={() => hit(2)} />
      <br />
      <img src={holeStates[3].hole} onClick={() => hit(3)} />
      <img src={holeStates[4].hole} onClick={() => hit(4)} />
      <img src={holeStates[5].hole} onClick={() => hit(5)} />
      <br />
      <img src={holeStates[6].hole} onClick={() => hit(6)} />
      <img src={holeStates[7].hole} onClick={() => hit(7)} />
      <img src={holeStates[8].hole} onClick={() => hit(8)} />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```